# Failed to export image to Drive from Google Colab

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, google-colab

I am trying to export an ee.Image to Google Drive and I get the error below. Has anyone come across this problem?

I am trying to export the prediction image produced from the earth engine AI platform to Drive or Asset and then import with python libraries like rasterio to be able to convert to a numpy array.

```
    # Turn into an array image for input to the model.
    array_image = stack.select(BANDS).float().toArray()

    # Point to the model hosted on AI Platform.  If you specified a 
    region other
    # than the default (us-central1) at model creation, specify it here.
    model = ee.Model.fromAiPlatformPredictor(
       projectName=PROJECT,
       modelName=MODEL_NAME,
       version=VERSION_NAME,
       # Can be anything, but don't make it too big.
       inputTileSize=[8, 8],
       # Keep this the same as your training data.
       proj=ee.Projection('EPSG:4326').atScale(30),
       fixInputProj=True,
       # Note the names here need to match what you specified in the
       # output dictionary you passed to the EEifier.
       outputBands={'output': {
          'type': ee.PixelType.float(),
          'dimensions': 1
          }
         },
    )

    # Output probability.
    predictions = model.predictImage(array_image).arrayGet([0])

    # Back-of-the-envelope decision rule.
    predicted = predictions.gt(0.8).selfMask()
```

The code below to prepare and start the export task:

```
    image_task2 = ee.batch.Export.image.toAsset(
      image = pred, 
      description = 'predict', 
      assetId = export_image, 
      region = GEOMETRY,
      scale = 30,
      maxPixels = 1e10
    )
    image_task2.start()
    image_task2.status()
```

then i got the error below:

```
            {'state': 'FAILED',
            'description': 'predict',
            'creation_timestamp_ms': 1667156828029,
            'update_timestamp_ms': 1667157309977,
            'start_timestamp_ms': 1667156850241,
            'task_type': 'EXPORT_IMAGE',
            'attempt': 1,
            'error_message': "Unable to deduce input tensor shape for 
    band: 'array'. Please 
            explicitly specify the inputShapes parameter.",
            'id': 'RABFPRI4FVESRSRDTHQVHGL6',
            'name': 'projects/earthengine- 
    legacy/operations/RABFPRI4FVESRSRDTHQVHGL6'}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The error indicates that there is a problem with the code that was run. We will need to see your code, not just the error.

Comment: I have edited above